Если ubuntu работает корректно в virtual box, то будет ли она корректно работать в качестве полноценной ОС?
Установил Ubuntu 24.04 на Virtual Box. Проверил: звук есть, управление отзывчивое и т. д. То есть машина работает как нужно. Моё устройство - Huawei MateBook D15.
Значит ли это, что при установке ubuntu в качестве полноценной ос она будет работать на моём устройстве так же, как и виртуальная машина?

Конечно нет, потому что в виртуальной машине устройства тоже виртуальные и не имеют никакого отношения к реальным устройствам (за исключением процессора)

«нет» не в смысле «не будет», а в смысле «не значит». Может, и будет работать корректно, если для этого самого Huawei MateBook D15 найдутся все подходящие драйвера (то есть модули ядра и связанные файлы прошивок) — однако беглый гyглинг намекает, что могут быть проблемы со звуком

Нельзя сказать точно, будет ли работать она как основная система корректно на твоей конфигурации, но факт в том что как гипервизор - Virtual Box достаточно требовательный, и забирает львинную долю ресурса, да и в целом 24.04 встаёт на любое ведёрко,поэтому я бы попробовал поставить на основную машину, всё таки есть разница в том что  у тебя машина работает на гипервизоре или же напрямую с железом, для теста можешь накатить ubuntu на флешку и запуститься, если всё норм то ставь на основу.

Virtual Box  умеет kvm и hyperv - он не требователен к ресурсам.
24.04 глючная ещё

Я не сказал что Virtual Box требователен,  я сказал что он выедает львинную долю ресурса, - по сравнению с другими гипервизорами,  Virtual Box хорош когда у тебя гостевая ОС - на пингвине, я бы присмотрелся к esxi если уж на то пошло, по поводу глючности не могу согласиться, не помню что бы у меня были какие то критические ошибки, но они конечно возможны и будут, 24.04 сырая ещё

цитата "Virtual Box достаточно требовательный"

львиная доля это 3% ? в режиме софтовой эмуляции кушает очень много. но это когда виртуализация отключена в биос. esxi на ноут... ну не знаю.


Virtul Box более требовательный если сравнивать с другими гипервизорами
Virtual Box - это гипервизор второго вида, ОН НЕ РАБОТАЕТ НАПРЯМУЮ С ЖЕЛЕЗОМ КОМПЬЮТЕРА
А вот гипервизоры Hyper-V, KVM работают без "посредников"


https://www.karma-group.ru/vybiraem-gipervizor-vmware-hyper-v-ili-kvm

виртуалбокс умеет работать без посредников уже лет 15.

Если Ubuntu работает корректно в VirtualBox, это обычно хороший знак, но не обязательно гарантирует, что она будет работать безупречно на физическом оборудовании. Вот тут можно посмотреть более-менее свежий отчет о том, что и как завелось под Fedora, думаю что для Убунты будет более-менее одинаково: https://github.com/jcchikikomori/linux-on-huawei-matebook-d15-2021/blob/master/README.md
Если кратко, то была проблема с сканером отпечатка пальцев и тихо работал спикер, в остальном всё работало корректно.
Если вы хотите проверить работоспособность системы, то используйте загрузку с живого диска (live CD).

Вот да, про лайв CD (лайв флешку) плюсую. Это явно более реальная проверка, чем запуск на виртулаке.
