Снос windows + установка linux
Я начинающий пользователь Linux, хочу установить дистрибутив Fedora в качестве основной ОС на ноутбук. Сейчас на ноутбуке стоит какая-то жутко стрёмная версия Windows, от которой хотелось бы избавиться + ноутбук китайский-китай, названия нет, все комплектующие, кроме проца, - абсолютный ноунейм, даже модель платы я не знаю. Вопроса у меня два:

Могу ли я отформатировать диск, а затем накатить Linux? В плане, мой комп не превратится в кирпич от подобной манипуляции? (Может ли быть такое, что я удалю какие-то важные драйвера, без которых ноут просто не сможет запуститься?)
Если Linux нормально работает на виртуалке (VirtualBox), означает ли это нормальную работу в качестве основной ОС?



Скорее всего да, драйвера винды не имеют никакого отношения к драйверам линукса; 2) А этот вопрос уже был https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1584243


Линукс в принципе не так сильно требователем к ресурсам как Windows, биос ты в любом случае не снесёшь - поэтому смело ставь федору.

Ну насчёт "биос не снесёшь" я бы поспорил https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=43795

А как ты rm -rf заюзаешь  на Windows?))) Он только хочет поставить федору...

Загрузится с ISO-образа федоры и снесёт
